# Drawn rectangle through mouse-move keeps drawing itself whenever the mouse moves, while showing the previous rectangles

Tags: javascript, html, css, draw, onmousemove

I have a very odd case, must I say. First, let me share you the code I'm working with:

```js
var CVSv2 = document.getElementById("CVS");


var ctx = CVSv2.getContext("2d");


var wH = window.innerHeight;
var wW = window.innerWidth;

CVS.height = wH;
CVS.width = wW;




DrawCanvas();

function DrawCanvas() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "silver";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, wW, wH);
  ctx.fill();
}






function Paddle(xPositie, yPositie, pWidth, pHeight) {

  this.yPositie = yPositie;
  this.xPositie = xPositie;
  this.pWidth = pWidth;
  this.pHeight = pHeight;


  this.DrawPaddle = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(this.xPositie, this.yPositie, this.pWidth, this.pHeight);
    ctx.fill();
  }

}





var paddlePong = new Paddle(0, 200, 15, 100);



CVSv2.onmousemove = function(arg) {
  paddlePong.yPositie = arg.pageY;
}



Animate();




function Animate() {
  paddlePong.DrawPaddle();
  setTimeout(Animate, 50);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="CVS">
</canvas>
```

When the above code is executed, one rectangle gets drawn, and whenever I move the mouse, a second, a third, and fourth, etc., gets drawn, BUT the previously drawn rectangles still appear! I want them to go away. I want it to be like an animation. I want it to remain one rectangle that moves everytime the mouse moves, and I don't want to see the previous rectangles with the previous Y-coordinate.

[This is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROkjp.png)

The rectangle somewhat in the middle gets drawn by default. When I move the mouse over the canvas, other ones pop up, and they overlap eachother as I move down (in the case of the photo's scenario). I've been stuck for this for 4 hours now, and I won't be surprised if it's a noob-mistake that's preventing it from working. It's 6am atm, so go figure. Anyway, hopefully any of you know how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use `clearRect()` (`ctx.clearRect(0,0,wW,wH)`) to clear the canvas and redraw everything like shown below.

```js
var CVSv2 = document.getElementById("CVS");


var ctx = CVSv2.getContext("2d");


var wH = window.innerHeight;
var wW = window.innerWidth;

CVS.height = wH;
CVS.width = wW;

function DrawCanvas() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "silver";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, wW, wH);
  ctx.fill();
}

function Paddle(xPositie, yPositie, pWidth, pHeight) {

  this.yPositie = yPositie;
  this.xPositie = xPositie;
  this.pWidth = pWidth;
  this.pHeight = pHeight;


  this.DrawPaddle = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(this.xPositie, this.yPositie, this.pWidth, this.pHeight);
    ctx.fill();
  }

}

var paddlePong = new Paddle(0, 200, 15, 100);

CVSv2.onmousemove = function(arg) {
  paddlePong.yPositie = arg.pageY;
}



Animate();




function Animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,wW,wH);
  DrawCanvas();
  paddlePong.DrawPaddle();
  setTimeout(Animate, 50);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="CVS">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks dude! It works! I actually tried to do the rectangle-clearing, but I didn't place it in the right function, so I was looking at the paddle itself to be the problem, but of course it's the canvas, because it needs to update after every motion! That's why, kids, we never stay up late until 6am trying to program. Anyway, this solved it, thanks! I knew it would be a noob-mistake on my end lol.